# How show foreach if/else in php

Tags: php, sql

**SQL Table** is shown below.

```
---------------------------------
|     id    |     product_id    |
---------------------------------
|     1     |       700         |
|     2     |     200,700,800   |
|     3     |        0          |
|     4     |    330,840,842    |
---------------------------------
```

And that code is written in **PHP** and For now I have the following code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM products"; $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {    
  if($row['product_id']) {
    $data = preg_split('/,/', $row['product_id']);
     if(is_array($data)) {
       foreach($data as $key => $value) {
           if($value == 605) {
               echo 'Yes.';
           }
       }
     } 
  }
}
```

The value of **605** is not displayed in the output.
Is that value in the database table or not?

If there is a database table
Show its output:

> **Yes.**

And if it doesn't exist
Show its output:

> **No.**

How can this be done in **PHP** and show its output?

Comment: Don't store data as comma separated values, it will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: I did not understand and Can you correct?

Comment: Store the values from `200,700,800` in separate rows instead. Will make it much easier to work with.

Comment: Go read up on proper database normalization.

Comment: Even with current provided data, there's no value `605` in it.

Comment: What does this have to do with phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$match = false;
//Your code
$query = "SELECT * FROM products";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($row['product_id']) {
        $data = preg_split('/,/', $row['product_id']);
        if (is_array($data)) {
            foreach($data as $key => $value) {
                if ($value == 605) {
                    $match = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
$match ? echo "Yes" : echo "No";
```

Comment: this will print for all record  and all element

Answer (score 0):

make one variable initialize with "No" then at the end of code just echo that value:

```
$result = "No";
//Your code
$query = "SELECT * FROM products";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($row['product_id']) {
        $data = preg_split('/,/', $row['product_id']);
        if (is_array($data)) {
            foreach($data as $key => $value) {
                if ($value == 605) {
                    $result = "Yes"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
echo $result
```

Comment: Warning: **mysqli_fetch_array()** expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/...

Comment: I checked, and It's a mistake of the code itself. **$result = "No";** -> **$results = "No";**

Comment: It was just referencing not exact code use variable name you want

Answer (score 0):

@jarlh is correct, continuing down this path will lead to many problems like this down the road. You should normalize the data so that you don't need to run such complex queries to find your data; the database system is designed to make this efficient and you are fighting that efficiency.

Aside from that, why not use SQL to search that column directly, something like ...`LIKE "%605%"`? Your requirement to do the parsing in PHP may have a good reason, but seems to be making this even more complex, since your database software can efficiently search within a column. Note that this assumes that all of your data is similar to the example data, that is, either three digits or a zero; otherwise you may have to add some additional search values to ensure that "6050" isn't matched as a false positive.

For that matter, you could select a count of values matching 'LIKE "%605%"' and then, in PHP, count the number of matches and then echo either Yes. or No. from in the PHP code.